# Use scala macros to copy method from class to companion object

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I'll get straight to the business.

Let's say that I have the following trait definition:

```
trait Routable{
    def routing(): String
}
```

And I'm defining the following class:

```
case class MyEvent(name: String, age: Int) extends Routable{
    override def routing(): String = "this is my routing key"
}
```

I'm trying to make a macro called `routeOf[MyEvent]` to return the routing key of the defined class.

I tried so many things for the last 3 days and I'm starting to wonder if it is possible at all...

My macro definition is:

`def routeOf[T]: Any = macro RouteOfMacro.impl[T]
def impl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: whitebox.Context): c.Tree`

But I can't find how to extract the method from the WeakTypeTag (and the internet is not full with examples).

So can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to make a macro called `routeOf[MyEvent]` to return the
>   routing key of the defined class.

The way your code is, it's not the routing key of the defined class, but of the instance.

If you create multiple `MyEvent`, there is no guarantee their routing keys would be alike.

What you can do is create a companion object `MyEvent` that derives from `Routable`. I feel `classTag` or `typeTag` may be enough for this case - do you know those? No macros should be needed. But until I know the larger picture, hard to say how I'd approach it. Can you reveal more? :)